# OpenVPN connects but cannot access servers

Tags: openvpn

My OpenVPN server connects, i can access the internet still but i am unable to access any of the servers on the LAN.

I have a virtual network which has an ip range of `172.31.0.0/16`

This VNET has 3 subnets which are:

- `172.31.0.0/24`
- `172.31.1.0/24`
- `172.31.0.0/24`

Traffic which is not going to the VNET does not need to go through the VPN.

server.conf

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh /etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 172.31.0.0 255.255.0.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/ta.key 0 # This file is secret
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

iptables

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

client

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote X.X.X.X 1194
route 172.31.0.0 255.255.0.0 vpn_gateway 3
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
tls-auth ta.key 1
ns-cert-type server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 1
```

IP forwarding is configured as can be seen below:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  1
```

Comment: Can you show rules from FORWARD table of iptables? Is your server the default gateway of the LAN? And what IP network is used in LAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. It seems that having comp-lzo enabled in my client config but not my server config was causing it to not work. Enabling this on the server fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

What is your ip forwarding set to?

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

If it is 0 then you need to do

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: It is set to 1.  I've added this to the original question too so it is easier for people to spot. Thanks!